# Problema con la propiedad fecha de un objeto que paso de AJAX a un Servicio Web

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, ajax

Tengo un formulario normal y corriente con tecnología [razor](/questions/tagged/razor), del cual obtengo distintos valores de distintos controles y los paso como objeto de `AJAX` a un servicio web de ASP.NET.

Tengo un `Datepicker` de jquery del cual tomo la fecha y con ella doy valor a una de las propiedades del objeto `Año_inicio`.

Este es el objeto:

Uso este código para:

```
var Atributs = {
    "Versio": VersioProv,
    "NIF": NIF,
    "Id_Experiencia": id_Exp,
    "Data_Inici": $("#txtExpDataInici").val(),
    "Data_Fi": $("#txtExpDataFi").val(),
    "Empresa": $("#txtExpEmpresa").val(),
    "Poblacio": $("#txtExpPoblacio").val(),
    "Treball": $("#txtExpTreball").val(),
    "Motiu_Baixa": $("#txtExpBaixa").val(),
    "Persona_Referencia": $("#txtExpPerRef").val(),
    "Tel_Persona": $("#txtExpTelPerRef").val(),
    "Salari_Brut": $("#txtExpSalariBrut").val()
};
```

El `Datepicker` está en formato `dd-MM-yyyy`, pero si el día supera el nº 12, me da este error y no entra ni al servicio web:

```
{
    "Message":"20-01-2001 no es un valor válido para DateTime.",
    "StackTrace":"   en System.ComponentModel.DateTimeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)\r\n
   en System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n
   en System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n
   en System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.AssignToPropertyOrField(Object propertyValue, Object o, String memberName, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError)\r\n
   en System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertDictionaryToObject(IDictionary`2 dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n
   en System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n
   en System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n
   en System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.StrongTypeParameters(IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n
   en System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n
   en System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n
   en System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)",
    "ExceptionType":"System.FormatException"
}
```

Es como si `AJAX` detectara que estoy en formato `MM-dd-yyyy` y como paso del nº 12, me da el error.

Tengo que dar algún formato a la fecha antes de enviarla al servicio web?

Comment: El problema no es Ajax, es de lado de servidor.

Comment: Pero,¿ porque no me entra en ningun punto de interrupción si realmente llega  a entrar al servicio web?

Comment: cuando dices ajax te refieres al Ajax.BeginForm o al $.ajax de jquery ? para realizar la llamada ajax como envias el form serializado al servidor ?

Answer (score 1):

Estas enviado la fecha en formato equivocado por temas de internacionalización (i18n)

Para no tener problemas con la cultura o región, envía la fecha en el formato:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd"
```

O si la cultura está en español

```
"dd/MM/yyyy"
```

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurren algunas alternativas

- Definir globalization en javascript, de esta forma indicas una cultura que concuerde con el formato de fecha que usas

[globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize)

Con esto al usar ajax reconocer la fecha en el formato de la cultura especificada.

- Otra es usar la librería

[moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

para parsear la fecha y convertirla al formato que ajax define (o sea MM-dd-yyyy) y enviarla con este formato 
Esta librería te permite trabajar con fechas de forma muy simple.